# Parent and child window have same handle names in IE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Iam not able to switch to the child window in IE. When  i checked the handle names of both parent and child, they are same. Can anyone let me know how to navigate to child window in this scenario?

the name of the parent handle is 6da0571c-7fca-45e0-ab3d-d237809f008b
the name of childhandl is e6da0571c-7fca-45e0-ab3d-d237809f008b

Comment: Can you update the question with your code trials?

Comment: One possible workaround may be using the KEYS interface to switch handles with a keyboard shortcut, if they are tabs, for example, the control key combined with the TAB key should twitch tabs.

Comment: The handles are the same because the windows are the same.  It is not a different window or tab, it merely appears as such when you view it.  I think you'll find the underlying HTML code has changed to reflect the new elements.

Comment: What do you mean by parent and child windows? Do you mean iframe? Also, is the problem specific to IE?